# Why is not running package in Data Client IBM? Why this is software doesnt see functions and procedures?

Tags: db2, package, ibm-data-studio

I have a problem with running of package in DATA CLIENT IBM. I created standard package of Data Client with specifications and etc. And it succesfully deployed, but it deployed without functions and procedure. And after running of package, I see empty windows where I need to choose procedure and function, which will run. After that I click to NEXT, and It doesnt do anything.

Comment: Edit your question to say What version of IBM Data Studio? You can see this in Help > About IBM Data Studio.

Comment: When you created your deployment-group, did you change from the default option , and instead choose "Stop and rollback on error" ?